# Access Ionic Storage directly from Swift via WkWebView

Tags: ios, swift, ionic-framework, ionic-storage

I have an app that was initially developed with Ionic 4 and it's currently being re-developed in Swift.
Once the new Swift app get's rolled out I want to read out the old user settings that were stored with Ionic Storage so that I can process and convert them into the new format.

How could I possibly access the old Ionic Storage data directly from Swift when the app gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the Ionic app data was stored in an IndexedDB  (think that's the default for Ionic)

Problem: Ionic and Cordova apps run a GCDWebserver under http://localhost to load the HTML/Javascript

So I first had to setup a GCDWebserver in my Swift app and bind it to localhost and load it in a headless WkWebView

```
    let w  = GCDWebServer()
    let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.addSubview(webView)

    let mainBundle = Bundle.main
    let folderPath = mainBundle.path(forResource: "www", ofType: nil)

    w.addGETHandler(forBasePath: "/", directoryPath: folderPath!, indexFilename: "ionicstorage.html", cacheAge: 0, allowRangeRequests: true)

    do {
        try w.start(options: ["Port": 8080,
                              "BindToLocalhost": true  ] )
    } catch  {
        print(error)
    }


    webView.load( URLRequest(url:  w.serverURL! ))
```

also had to add this to my projects target properties in order to make requests to http://localhost possible:

```
<dict>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
<key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
<dict>
    <key>localhost</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Then in the ionicstorage.html file I added the JS code to access the stored ionic data and to send it back to Swift via a WKScriptMessageHandler:

```
let openRequest = indexedDB.open("_ionicstorage", 2);

        openRequest.onsuccess = function () {
            let db = openRequest.result;

            let transaction = db.transaction("_ionickv", "readwrite");

            let data = transaction.objectStore("_ionickv");

            let settings = data.get("settings")
            settings.onsuccess = function () {
                if (settings.result !== undefined) {
                    window.webkit.messageHandlers.getSettings.postMessage(String(settings.result));
                } else {
                    window.webkit.messageHandlers.getSettings.postMessage("");
                }
            };
}
```

Only tested this in the Simulator so far and it works.
I think on an actual device the http port should be 80 instead of 8080